# Laravel9+Breeze のマルチ認証で、認証時に違うテーブルを参照してしまう（ログインできない）

Tags: laravel

こちらのサイトを参考にマルチ認証を実現しようとしています。
[Laravel Breezeでマルチ認証(Multi Authentification)の徹底解説](https://reffect.co.jp/laravel/breeze_multi_auth)

user,adminの２つの認証を作成しています。登録までは問題なく処理できました。
しかし、user,adminの情報でログインをしようしても、常にusersテーブルを参照してしまいます。
adminでログインすることが出来ません（adminのログイン画面でも）を

この原因は何が考えられるでしょうか？

【追記】
`config\auth.php` の `'guards' => ['web' => [` の `'provider' => 'users',` を `'provider' => 'admins',` に変えたところ、adminでログインできました（adminでしかログインできない）
ただ、この設定がどこに影響しているのか掴みきれていません

【追記】
`config\auth.php` の `'guards' => ['web' => [` を `'aaa' => [` に変えたところ
`InvalidArgumentException Auth guard [web] is not defined.`
エラーが発生しました。webは必須なんでしょうか？

```
// config/auth.php　一部
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\admin::class,
        ],
```

```
// app\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest.php　一部
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        $this->is('admin/*') ? $guard = 'admin' : $guard = 'web';

        if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }
```

```
// app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php　一部
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            if($request->is('admin/*')){
                return route('admin.login');
            }
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

```
// routes\admin.php　一部
    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
        ->middleware('guest:admin')
                ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware('guest:admin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やろうとしている方法は正しいです。
あとはコード上のちょっとしたミスを修正すれば動作しそうですね。
https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/ja/authentication.html#accessing-specific-guard-instances

```
$this->is('admin/*') ? $guard = 'admin' : $guard = 'web';
```

せっかくここでガードを切り替えているので、

```
Auth::attempt(...)
```

この部分を

```
Auth::guard($guard)->attempt(...)
```

このようにすれば意図通りの動作になると思います。

せっかくなのでもう少し深堀りすると、

> config\auth.php の 'web' => [ を 'aaa' => [ に変えたところ
> InvalidArgumentException Auth guard [web] is not defined.
> エラーが発生しました。webは必須なんでしょうか？

必ずしも必須ではありませんが、もう少し上の方に `'defaults'` という設定がありそこで `'web'` が指定されていないでしょうか？この設定が `guard()` を指定しなかった場合のデフォルトの認証先です。現在のコードだと `guard()` は指定せずデフォルトで認証するようにしている（しかしデフォルトの `web` が無い）のでエラー、といいう順序ですね。

> config\auth.php の 'provider' => 'users', を 'provider' => 'admins', に変えた> ところ、adminでログインできました（adminでしかログインできない）
> ただ、この設定がどこに影響しているのか掴みきれていません

`guards.*.provider`の設定が `providers.*` に定義されている、という関係です。
つまり上の設定変更は「ガード『web』のプロバイダ設定を『admins』」に変更」ですが、それは「ガード『admin』と同様の設定なので、ご覧の通り「adminでしかログインできない」となったわけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
`if (! Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
`
のように変更してみました。変更点はあっているでしょうか。
しかしながら、まだログインできませんでした。

'defaults' はそのような使い方をするのですね。このあたりがほとんど理解できていないので勉強になりました。

Comment: `if (! Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($this->only` のようにしたところ、切り替えてログインできました。全てのログインページで admin にログインするようになりました。ということは、その上の `$this->is('admin/*') ? ` が正しく動いていないのかもしれません

Comment: 重要な情報を忘れていました。レンタルサーバーに設置するため、現在 url 内に /public をつけてアクセスしていました。そのために処理が `agent` ではなく `public` として処理されている可能性があります。

Comment: なるほどそれが原因ですね。

`admin/*` を `public/admin/*` として判定すれば解決しそうですが、それだと `public` というディレクトリ名が変更された時にプログラムも一緒に変更しなければならないのが面倒そうです。 `php artisan serve` で開発サーバで動作させた時もおそらく動きません。

なので`->name('login')` というコードが出てきますがこれを少し修正して、管理者と一般ユーザーとで `login` とは別の名前（例えば `admin.login` / `user.login` ）を付けてあげた上で

https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/ja/requests.html#inspecting-the-request-path

is()ではなくrouteIs()で判定してやる、とすればより良い実装になりそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。イレギュラーな作り方が問題を複雑にしていました。そこで本来の public で DocumentRoot に指定しました。

Comment: その上で処理をしてもやはり、adminログイン画面で、userでしかログインできない状態が続いています。 `$this->is('admin/*') ? $guard = 'admin' : $guard = 'web';` が怪しいので、 `\Log::debug("guard=>".$guard);` で調べてみたところ `local.DEBUG: guard=>web ` という結果になりました。

Comment: `$this->is('admin/*')` が `trueにならない` のが原因だと思われます。
他の方法として、 `$this->routeIs('admin/*)'` にしてみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした

Comment: 原因がわかりました。質問のため一部コードを省略して載せていたのですが、その部分で上書きしているところを見つけました。混乱させてしまってすみません。

Comment: 解決の肝としては、最初に教えていただいた `Auth::guard($guard)->attempt(` にすることでした。本当にありがとうございます！